# How do I fix the 'SignatureDoesNotMatch' error while signing the S3 URL in Node?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I'm trying to get the signed URL of the files that I've uploaded in S3 bucket. I'm successfully getting the signed URL's but whenever I visit them I get an error saying **The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.**

Although the *accessKey* and *secretAccessKey* I provided are perfectly fine because I'm using the same keys while putting an object in s3 bucket.

**import and AWS config**

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const region = 'us-west-1';

AWS.config.update({
 region: region,
});

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
 apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
 accessKeyId: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
 secretAccessKey:  process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
});
const mainBucketName = 'test-bucket';
```

**putObject method for uploading that receives bucket,key and file as params**

```
module.exports.putObject = (bucketName, key, file)=>{

return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    const fileName = `${key}-${file.originalname}`;
    s3.putObject({
        Bucket: `${mainBucketName}/${bucketName}`,
        Key: fileName,
        Body: file.buffer,
        ContentType: file.mimetype,

    }, function(err, data){
        if(err)
            reject(err)
        resolve(fileName);
    });
})
}
```

**method to sign the URl**

```
module.exports.getSignedUrls = (bucketName, key)=>{
return s3.getSignedUrl('getObject',{
    Bucket: `${mainBucketName}/${bucketName}`,
    Key: key,
    Expires:3600,
});

}
```

This is response I get when I call the

`getSignedurls('5c63340d8bdeb62f843d8df0','9cf2adefb8061edacfdc71b044e54b17ec6cc887-qqqq.png')`

method.

```
'https://test-bucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/5c63340d8bdeb62f843d8df0/9cf2adefb8061edacfdc71b044e54b17ec6cc887-qqqq.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIFKF7Z2V6SHUBMFA&Expires=1550168664&Signature=33mtb6zMunXNi8W5D95BRfE%2FNqg%3D'
```

and this is the response i get when I visit the URL

```
<Error>
 <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
 <Message>
  The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
 </Message>
 <AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAIFKF7Z2V6SHUBMFA</AWSAccessKeyId>
 <StringToSign>
  GET 1550168664 /test-bucket/5c63340d8bdeb62f843d8df0/9cf2adefb8061edacfdc71b044e54b17ec6cc887-qqqq.png
 </StringToSign>
<SignatureProvided>33mtb6zMunXNi8W5D95BRfE/Nqg='</SignatureProvided>
<StringToSignBytes>
47 45 54 0a 0a 0a 31 35 35 30 31 36 38 36 36 34 0a 2f 61 73 73 65 74 74 72 61 63 6b 65 72 2d 61 74 74 61 63 68 6d 65 6e 74 73 2d 73 74 61 67 69 6e 67 2f 35 63 36 33 33 34 30 64 38 62 64 65 62 36 32 66 38 34 33 64 38 64 66 30 2f 39 63 66 32 61 64 65 66 62 38 30 36 31 65 64 61 63 66 64 63 37 31 62 30 34 34 65 35 34 62 31 37 65 63 36 63 63 38 38 37 2d 71 71 71 71 2e 70 6e 67
</StringToSignBytes>
<RequestId>AC2452AF7131E916</RequestId>
<HostId>
cGcMHQacSYJ3C7e7viZ+CsnfQ0jkxs+uaBCtzmIe3f740euA0uOW5hQcEiTrr5zWXQeCGXZggiw=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: `Bucket: \`${mainBucketName}/${bucketName}\`,` does not make sense.  `Bucket` expects the name of a bucket, and cannot contain the character `/`.  Additionally, *"I'm successfully getting the signed URL's"* is inaccurate. You don't "get" signed URLs.  You *generate* them, with no service interaction.  Generating a signed URL doesn't fail, even if the bucket or object doesn't exist.

Comment: In fact I didn't get any errors while adding `/` in the bucket name and my files are being uploaded the way I expected. I tried

 Bucket: `${mainBucketName}`,
 Key: `${bucketName}/${fileName}`
`
and still getting the same error.